# Raspbian apt-get dependency error with Python?

Tags: raspbian, python, apt

I've ran the following command on Raspbian:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But now when I try to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

or any other `apt-get` command, I got this error and I can't get rid of it:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
idle:  Depends: python (= 2.7.3-4) 
but 2.7.3-4 + deb7u1 must be installed 
python: Depends: python-minimal (= 2.7.3-4 + deb7u1) 
but 2.7.3-4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies.
Try 'apt-get-f install' with no packages
```

Running:

```
$ apt-get install -f
```

I get this error:

```
Unpacking python-minimal 2.7.3-4
(using ... / python-minimal_2.7.3 deb7u1_all.deb-4 +)
...segmentation fault 
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 139 
dpkg: attempt to run the script from the new package instead 
...segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing / 
var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.3-4deb7u1_all.deb 
+ (- unpack): subprocess new pre-removal script
returned error exit status 139 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
/ var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.3-4 +deb7u1_all.d
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also getting same error while installing python, it shows unmet dependencies error. I tried above solutions but getting errors.

Comment: did you also run apt-get update?

Answer (score 1):

First, try `apt-get install -f`.  From the man page:

> **-f, --fix-broken**
>
> Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can
>   omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If
>   packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem.
>   The option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time;
>   APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
>   system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so
>   corrupt as to require        manual intervention (which usually means
>   using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending
>   packages).

If that does not work out, try `python --version`; you should get `Python 2.7.3`.  If instead you get another segmentation fault or other errors, try `apt-get install -f --reinstall python`.

Comment: with "python --version" I get Python 2.7.3 but with "apt-get install -f --reinstall python" I get the same error

Comment: Nobody can help me ?